# How do I add a shadow to the bottom of a UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code so far, but I just want a shadow at the bottom of a myView

```
myView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
```

to

```
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);
```

see if that works for you.

Comment: nope not working on my view. I still get a shadow on top